# Problem selecting from a partitioned external table after loading

Tags: python-3.x, impala, external-tables

My script does the following

1. load data from csv file into a dataframe to decide schema of the external table dynamically (column types to be int, string or boolean)
2. generate create partitioned external table statement
3. convert csv files into parquet format
4. execute create table statement with impala
5. create partitions in the table
6. copy files to hdfs
7. load data using "load data inpath" statement

I am having trouble selecting data from the external table. Impala will have trouble with datatype not matching between data and column type for some partitions. However, I can do counts with "select count(*), date from table group by date" without any problem. Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?